# Sequences that look like they have integer terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I've read somewhere about a sequence that is an integer for many terms but eventually loses the integer property. I remember it to be an April fool's joke in a problem column of some kind. I'd like to use it for a similar purpose, but the problem is that I can't recall the exact sequence.

The problem went something like this:

> Define a sequence $\{ a_n \}$ as "initial conditions", "recursive relation". Prove that $a_n$ is an integer for all $n$.

And of course it actually gives a number which is not an integer at approximately $n=$20?30?

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: The first $n$ terms of $(n!/k)_{k=1}^\infty$ are integers. Eventually, the terms are not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of [Göbel sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoebelsSequence.html) where $a_n = \big(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k^2\big)/n$:

https://oeis.org/search?q=%22not+always+integral%22&sort=&language=english&go=Search

See also [Somos sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence), and this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13601/a-weird-sequence-with-a-non-integral-term).

Answer (score 2):

One of possible examples.

When I was young student, I've read about number $\pi$ and series

$$
\zeta(2n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^{2n}}.
$$

Well known identities/equalities:

$$
\zeta(2) = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}, 
$$
$$
\zeta(4) = \dfrac{\pi^4}{90}, 
$$ 
$$
\zeta(6) = \dfrac{\pi^6}{945}, 
$$ 
$$
...
$$

I expected (I was convinced) that all denominators here are integer numbers:
$$
a_n = \dfrac{\pi^{2n}}{\zeta(2n)} \in \mathbb{N}. (???)
$$

Indeed, first terms are integer:
$$
a_1=6, ~~~ a_2=90, ~~~ a_3=945, ~~~ a_4=9450, ~~~ a_5 = 93555,
$$
but
$$
a_6 = 924041+\frac{544}{691} \notin \mathbb{N}.
$$

---

Related sequence: reciprocal [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number):

$1, -2, 6, 0, -30, 0, 42, 0, 30, 0, \dfrac{66}{5}, \ldots .$